# Drop Dataframe index when writing to HDFStore

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

Is there some way to prevent writing the integer index of a Dataframe to HDF5, when using

```
HDFStore.append
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the internal representation of the HDF file in the store. Looks like it knows what it is doing. I was most concerned with retrieving date indexes, which Pandas handles well